# php shortcode with id

Tags: php, regex, include, shortcode

I need a piece of code that transforms

```
[plugin-testplugin]
```

to a PHP include. This is working fine.

However, I want to have something more like this:

```
[plugin-testplugin 12]
```

where the testplugin only shows the content with 12 as id in the database.

How can I accomplish this?

This is my code:

```
$regex = '~\[plugin-([^]]+)]~';
$plugin = htmlspecialchars_decode($page['plugin']);
$parts = preg_split($regex, $plugin, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

foreach($parts as $k => $v){
    if($k & 1)
        include('plugins/'.$v.'/'.$v.'.php');
    else
        echo htmlspecialchars_decode($v);
}
```

Comment: Is 'plugins' within a valid include path ?
Try running it with `foreach($parts as $k => $v){
    if($k & 1)
        var_dump('plugins/'.$v.'/'.$v.'.php');
    else
        echo htmlspecialchars_decode($v);
}`

That will tell you which physical file php is trying to load, is this a valid filepath?, are the variables what you expect them to be, does it even match the if statement, etc, etc ??

Comment: Did you register your shortcode handlers in functions.php? show your functions.php as well

Comment: @GreensterRox the code i am showing is working, but only for the first option. I want to implement something where I can show a specific id.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i don't have a functions.php. This is all the code I have to show the plugin. What is a right direction to make something ike i want?

Comment: @Saypontigohe did you create the plugin by yourself from strectch?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes I did. The plugin is made from scratch, same for the content management system.

Comment: what cms u using?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile the cms is also custom made by me. It is a private content management system for a couple of projects.